# Can't access result from a method in another

Tags: java, scope

I'm having an issue with scope and I don't know how to solve it. Here's a simple program to illustrate my problem:

```
public class testing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test(1,2);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public static int test(int x, int y) {
        int answer = x + y;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

So I pass a couple parameters to the test method and I return answer, so shouldn't I be able to access the result of answer in my main method? But I can't, I get an error. What am I doing wrong? Java is telling me that I can't access answer, that the scope doesn't extend to the main method even though I put the return statement in the test method. How else can I return answer then (without passing it as a parameter)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't store the `return value` in any variable. Also, the variable `answer` is defined *locally* in `test` method, and will not be visible in `main` method. Hence, you would have got the *compiler error* in your code.

You need to have this code in your main method: -

```
int result = test(1,2);
System.out.println(result);
```

Now, what happens here is, it stores the `return value` of `test(1, 2)` in a *local variable* `result`, which has nothing to do with the `answer` variable defined in `test` method. And then you simply print the `result` back.

Furthermore, you can change your `test` method to: -

```
public static int test(int x, int y) {
    // int answer = x + y; // No need to define a local variable.
    return x + y;
}
```

and your main method can be modified to: -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test(1, 2));
}
```

Note that, this eliminates the need to declare the local variables (either in `main` or `test` method).

Comment: Ahh, I understand now! Thank you, that explains everything!

Comment: @user2022185.. You might take a look at updated answer, for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

> So I pass a couple parameters to the test method and I return answer, so shouldn't I be able to access the result of answer in my main method?

No, because you didn't declare it in your `main` method. It's completely local to your `test` method. You could create umpteen different `answer` variables in different methods, and they'd all be entirely separate.

Instead, you need to use the return value from the method when you call it. For example:

```
int result = test(1, 2);
System.out.println(result);
```

This deliberately uses a different variable name to emphasize the independence of the variable in `main` from the one in `test`, but they *could* have the same name, with exactly the same result.

Or without using a local variable in `main` at all:

```
System.out.println(test(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int answer = test(1,2);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope of answer is only within the method `test()` if you wish to print the value of answer you need to write:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
System.out.println(test(1,2));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the return value:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int answer = test(1,2);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

The local variable `answer` declared in method `test` is invisible outside the method. Another approach would be to move the declaration of `answer` to class scope (in which case `test` does would not need to return a value at all):

```
public class testing {
    static int answer;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test(1,2);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public static void test(int x, int y) {
        answer = x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling method and ignoring results:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   test(1,2);
   System.out.println(answer);
```

}

Change it to:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int answer = test(1,2);
  System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `answer` variable is a local one in the static `test` method. It is not visible from outside and was returned as a result when you called the method, but you did not save it anywhere.

What you should've done is to declare another variable that will store your result

`int answer = test(1, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question - how to make the result of `test` accessible without returning an argument, you could declare `answer` as a private instance field (`private static int answer;`). Then it would be accessible via the main method, but not outside the class. Depends on the application whether this is more useful than passing it back as a return value. I would recommend you getting familiar with the keywords `static`, `private`, `public` etc. to see what the different combinations are for methods, classes and variables.